# Type casting and generic types

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there any way to type cast by a generic type's class, into a method which does not have a parameter for generic types?

I'm trying to learn how to write excel files using Apache POI. I have a method that stores data into the cells of an .xls file from a generic 2D array, which you can see below.

```
private static <T> void insert2dArrayToSheet(T[][] array, int sheetNumber) {
    workbook.createSheet("Sheet " + (sheetNumber + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber).createRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber).getRow(i).createCell(j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (isNumericData(array[i][j])) {
                workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber).getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellValue((Integer) array[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber).getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellValue(array[i][j].toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that all numeric data should be stored into cells with their own data type, and all other types of data as Strings.The method from the POI API I want to use (*Cell.setCellValue(*)) has a variation which accepts a double as an argument, but I can't cast anything by the primitive data type double since the array is generic, and I can't cast everything with a single wrapper class like Integer (which I've currently done) because that wouldn't work with Doubles for example.

What I really wanted to do was check if the data type of an index in the array is numeric, and then storing the data from the index by casting it with it's own class. I thought I could do by first checking if it's a numeric data type with this method,

```
private static <T> boolean isNumericData(T object) {
    if (object.getClass() == Integer.class || object.getClass() == Float.class || object.getClass() == Double.class
            || object.getClass() == Short.class || object.getClass() == Long.class || object.getClass() == Byte.class) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and casting it with a syntax that would be something like this:

```
workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber).getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellValue((array[i][j].getClass()) array[i][j]);
```

The syntax above for casting is not valid though. Since I will probably work with arrays that have different data types in different indices, the only option I see is to achieve what I want would be to create if-statements checking an index for each numeric data type, storing the data by casting it with the corresponding data type, and an else-statement for Strings.

What would be the simplest/most correct way to achieve what I want?

P.S. Feel free to correct me if I've misunderstood any concepts or terminology.

Comment: I think the isNumericData does not need types.  I think you can do "public static boolean isNumericData(Object object) { return (object instanceof Number); }

Comment: java casts automatically numeric fields to their primitive types, you should not have to cast arguments in this case. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html